# Is it possible to generate roughness and normal texture maps from procedural textures inside blender?

Tags: texturing

Basically can blender be used to create all pbr maps from a single texture just like substance bitmap to material.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create pbr maps such as roughness, normal etc. To this, you must first know how to bake textures. In the bake section, instead of combined, select the desired map and bake it.

Comment: It should be noted Blender will give you the individual textures, only if you provide that information. It will not analyze a single image and build the maps. You still need to provide textures for diffuse, specular, normal, height, hardness, etc.  Blender can then bake this information to UV Maps.